# Error when redefining a different xml Namespace to an existing alias using XElement with System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I try programming the following xml document (simplified) as code:

```
<P xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/x/2010/manifest" 
   xmlns:ab="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest" 
   xmlns:ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest">
    <ab:Ex xmlns:ab="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest">
    </ab:Ex>
</P>
```

Now an element redefines the namespace:

```
xmlns:ab="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest".
```

how do I get the element into my program? It is obviously valid because I can load the xml file like this:

```
Add(new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab")
```

I get the error message:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'The prefix 'ab' cannot be redefined from 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest' to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest' within the same start element tag.'

Actually logical (redefinition) but when I load the document, the element is accepted.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace xmltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"c:\simple.xml", LoadOptions.None);
            System.Console.WriteLine(doc1.ToString());

            //Create new
            XNamespace ab = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest";
            XNamespace nsx = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/x/2010/manifest";
            XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""), 
                new XElement(nsx + "P"));
            doc2.Element(nsx + "P").Add(new XAttribute("xmlns", 
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/x/2010/manifest"));
            doc2.Element(nsx + "P").Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab", 
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest"));
            doc2.Element(nsx + "P").Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ac", 
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest"));

            XElement xml = new XElement(ab + "Ex");
            //--> Below does not work work
            xml.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab",
                 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest"));
            doc2.Element(nsx + "P").Add(xml);
            System.Console.WriteLine(doc2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks really confusing to repurpose an in-scope namespace alias on an inner element which seems ambiguous as to which namespace it may belong. Why not just use a new alias for the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest` - this would surely be easier to read / less surprising?

Comment: Change From : XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab"  To : ab.NamespaceName

Comment: The whole XML is based on a Microsoft file (simplified in the example) and I want to automate the creation. At the moment I only have the idea to insert the elements via a string replace (after save).

Comment: I am unfortunately getting an exception for "ab.NamespaceName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, because

```
<ab:Ex xmlns:ab="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest">
```

actually means that Ex is to be defined in the *new* namespace (2013), you can get what you want by defining Ex in the new namespace, i.e. something like:

```
XNamespace abOld = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest";
XNamespace abNew = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest";
XNamespace nsx = ...

XElement xml = new XElement(abNew + "Ex");
xml.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ab", 
                       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest"));
```

However, repurposing the alias of an existing namespace just so that you can use the same alias is going to be really confusing to future maintenance - as the alias leaves scope, it will revert to it's old definition. I would recommend that you at least create different, unique aliases for the 2010 and 2013 namespaces.

Also, unless the intended consumer of the Xml was buggy, and required specific aliases or namespace scopes, I would generally avoid micro-managing the namespace aliasing and namespace scoping - let Linq to Xml manage that for you.

For instance, how about just:

```
XNamespace abOld = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2010/manifest";
XNamespace abNew = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/a/2013/manifest";

// Build up the document by providing element, attribute + applicable namespaces:
var root = new XElement(abOld + "P", 
    new XElement(abNew + "Ex"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's how it works. I've tried so much already!